# How to access files on Spark master?

Tags: apache-spark

I have set up a Spark standalone cluster with just one master node.

So I use `spark-shell --master spark://remote-url:7077` to access the Spark cluster fine.

Is it possible to let Spark have access to the file system on the **master** node? Because I already have a large file stored on there.

How do I do that? Total Spark noob here.

Comment: You can place the file on HDFS and access the file through "hdfs:///path/file".

Comment: How I "place the file on HDFS"?

Comment: You can use below command:

hdfs dfs -put localfile hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Hadoop` cluster then you can keep file at `HDFS` which will be accessible to all nodes. Here is the command that can help you to put file at HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -put <local path> <hdfs path>
```

or

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <local path> <hdfs path>
```

or 
    hdfs dfs -put   
Since you have mentioned that you are using **Spark in standalone mode** then I am suspecting that ***you don't have Hadoop cluster*** (simply not have any `resource manager` like `Yarn`). In that case you can create share folder which will be accessible to all nodes. You can  places all Jars and required file there.

Below is the link that will help you create share folder in Linux.

https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/nfs-share

Suppose if you have created share folder name as **Share_Box** then you can give path of Jar and file as below example.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client -master spark://remote-url:7077 --class com.example.main /Share_Box/Jars/test_spark.jar /Share_Box/config/application.conf
```